# Targer activity doesn't starts after clicking the button its navigate to main.activity

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dao, implementation

in my first Android App I've created the NoteActivity (which is not MainActivity) and fragments, database, viewmodels, navigation etc. for this activity.

The problem is when i open the app using emulator after clicking the button which should open NoteActivity its navigates to MainActivity instead.

I think there's meybe some problem in AndroidManifest or build.gradle implementations.

AndroidManifest (DzennikPodrozy is mentioned NoteActivity) here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DuoTravel_v14"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".DzennikPodrozy"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="andorid.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapyActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mapy"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DuoTravel_v14" />

        <activity
            android:name=".StronaGlowna"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="*************************************" />
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")                                  
    id("kotlin-kapt")                                       
                                                           
}

android {
    namespace = "pl.duotravel.duotravel_v14"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "pl.duotravel.duotravel_v14"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        kapt {
            correctErrorTypes = true
        }

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"

    }
    buildFeatures{                           
        viewBinding = true
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation ("pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0")  

    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2")          
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5") 
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

   


    // Architectural Components
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0")

    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0")


    // Navigation Components
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.5")

}
```

Build.gradle (Project)

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.SupportedPropertyType.Collection.List.type

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.3" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1")
        classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath ("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.0")

    }
}
```

For a long team Ive been searching the problem in the NoteActivity codes but its seem to be complete.

Its not a problem if You need more codes from the project to help me

Thank You guys!

Answer (score 0):

The mainfest (what the App contains) determines what the App consists of, including the activity that is first started.

The activity that has the **action** **`.MAIN`** is the activity that is started. By default when you create a project it will be MainActivity.

i.e. you have

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

- this is saying that it is **MainActivity** that is the ***MAIN*** activity and thus the activity that is first started.

To make the **DzennikPodrozy** the activity that is started then move the **action** from the MainActivity to the DzennikPodrozy activity.

A simplified minimal example. Steps taken:-

- new empty project created, then
- addition of a new empty activity DzennikPodrozy, then
- the layout for each changed so the textview (the only view) displays the activity name and for the DzennikPodrozy activity the background of the TextView is set to teal.

So the manifest includes:-

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DzennikPodrozy"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and when the App runs MainActivity is started:-

[image]

Changing the manifest to:-

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DzennikPodrozy"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
    </activity>
```

Then :-

[image]

i.e. the TextView has the Teal background as per the layout for the DzennikPodrozy activity.